# Calculating TurfJS planepoint values for a set of points / Get containing feature with TurfJS

Tags: tin, turf

[Turf.planepoint()](http://turfjs.org/docs/#planepoint) calculates the z value for a point that falls on the plane of a triangle.

I am struggling to make this work with a tin from [turf.tin()](http://turfjs.org/docs/#tin) and a set of points.

**Is there a turf function that returns the feature which contains a point?**

Testing every triangle against every point isn't feasible.

Turf features doesn't seem to have IDs. I could create an ID for every triangle, then [turf.tag()](http://turfjs.org/docs/#tag) the IDs to the points and finally select the triangle from the tin feature set by this id before evaluating the turf.planepoint().

Ideally turf.planepoint() would accept feature collections but I could easily get there if I only could get the containing feature for each point.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an integer index and turf.tag() the points with the integer index is pretty quick and works a treat. As a bonus I can use the index of the tin in the feature array, so the whole thing is pretty quick.

[image]

Here is a bit of code in case you are trying to replicate this.

```
var n = tin.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tin.features[i].properties.i = i;
}

var tagged_ = turf.tag(dots, tin, 'i', 'tin');
var n = tagged_.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (tagged_.features[i].properties.tin) {
    tagged_.features[i].properties.dt = turf.planepoint(
      tagged_.features[i],
      tin.features[tagged_.features[i].properties.tin]
    );
  }
}
```